# PSR-4 autoloader issue

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have trouble seeing what am I doing wrong with autoloader. My folder structure is as follows:

```
| - src/
|    - Files/
|        - Bla.php
|    - Models/
|        - ...
| - vendor/
|     - ...
| composer.json
```

And `composer.json` autoload part looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Migrations\\" : "src/"
    }
}
```

Now the `Bla.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Migrations\Files;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

final class Bla extends AbstractMigration
{
    ...
}
```

And I am getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration' not found in /var/www/html/migrations/src/Files/Bla.php
```

When I look at the `vendor` folder, package is there. From my IDE also indexing works fine so that I can CMD+click to the `AbstractMigration` file without problem.

I have tried deleting the `vendor` folder, clearing composer cache, doing a dump-autoload and reinstalling all packages, but nothing seems to work.

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Are you using Composer and including the Composer autoload file?

Comment: Where should I do that? I don't remember doing that in projects before? I was using some composer stub code though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the Composer autoload file otherwise your application doesn't know what classes exist.  It is a file created by composer when you install the dependencies, a lot of frameworks that use Composer will include this file for you automatically, but if you are not using a framework you will need to include the file yourself.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Where you need to put it will depend on your application but its best to load as early as possible, if you have a bootstrap file then that would be the place to put it.

You can read about it [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Comment: This does resolve it, but how come my other project knows how to include it by itself? Project structure is the same from the composer perspective in a way that `src`, `vendor` and `composer.json` are at the same folder level

Comment: Are your other project using a framework or any bootstrap code?  Composer can also use PDR-0 class mapping which is direct folder to namespace matching, so its possible your previous projects have all been using PSR-0.  Most packages now though use PSR-4 which will require the venodr/autoload file

Comment: No, the project is pure PSR-4, and only places the `autoload` gets included is in PHP code sniffer which is a dependency by itself inside `vendor` folder. For this specific project, its folders are PSR-0, and my `migration` folder is PSR-4, but the composer autoloader doesn't PSR-0 autoload the `migration` folder, so I don't think it should make a difference?

Comment: It's quite hard to say without seeing more of both projects. Its also been a while since I've got in-depth in composer as just about all my projects are now built with Laravel, which handles all the autoload. But from memory all the autoload does is create an autoload register which maps directories/class names to the correct files and includes it when requested.

Comment: So, if you have an spl_autoloader registered in your project, that could be one reason its not needed it.  If you include or require the files for your project then that also negates the need for an autoloader, once the file is found by php it knows where to go to get the class.